# Redirecting through .htaccess is not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am using Ubuntu 19.10 with LAMP installed.
**.htaccess** file stored inside `/EX/clean_url/handp/` folder-

```
RewriteEngine on
Options -Indexes
Redirect /EX/clean_url/handp/access_denied.php
```

So I do not want to show the folder structure of `handp`.
When I try to see the folder structure of `handp` in Google-Chrome then it is redirecting back to `access_denied.php` page (this is good) but it is not displaying the content of `access_denied.php` page because Google-Chrome' is giving me the error

> This page isn't working
> localhost redirected you too many times.
> Try clearing your cookies.
> ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

I am also not able to view the file's content present inside the `handp` folder like `form.php` etc. It is redirecting back to `access_denied.php` page with same Google-Chrome error as above.

Answer (score 0):

You are redirecting any attempt to access the `handp` folder. That includes valid attempts and `access_denied.php`. Hence you're getting the error *"redirected you too many times"*. It redirects you to the file, but because that file is inside that folder, it just triggers another redirect resulting in an infinite loop.

Try this instead:

```
RewriteEngine On 
# If requested filename is not an existing file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# If requested filename is not an existing directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
# Rewrite the url
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ https://your_domain.com/handp/access_denied.php [R,L]
```

This should redirect only if someone is trying to access a file or folder inside `handp` that doesn't exist.

Comment: I just want to **NOT** show the folder structure of `handp` like if someone give the path to that folder in a browser to see what's inside of it.

Comment: @Abhishekkamal And that is what this does. If you browse towards a folder, your server automaticly tries to serve an index file. Like `index.html` or `index.php` (depending on server setup). If such a file doesn't exist, it returns the folder structure or a 404 error (again, depending on setup). This htaccess redirects if the visitor tries to get anything that doesn't exist. But you could also just create an `index.html` file which redirects to your access denied file and be done with it.

Answer (score 0):

> I just want to NOT show the folder structure of handp like if someone give the path to that folder in a browser to see what's inside of it.

If you simply want to prevent the auto-generated directory structure being generated from mod_autoindex then all you need is:

```
Options -Indexes
```

(Which is what you already have.)

This will result in a 403 Forbidden response for any user that requests the directory directly.

If you want to return a custom 403 response then configure an `ErrorDocument` - you shouldn't be externally redirecting (a 3xx response) to what appears to be an error document.

For example:

```
ErrorDocument 403 /EX/clean_url/handp/access_denied.php
```

---

> **UPDATE:** why it is not working when i gave relative path like `./access_denied.php`

The `ErrorDocument` directive requires a *document-root relative* URL-path, starting with a slash. A *relative* path is not supported. If you specify a relative path like `./access_denied.php` (or `access_denied.php`) then it will be seen as literal text and it will simply output the string "./access_denied.php".

> why Redirect is not working in my `.htaccess`
> **.htaccess** file stored inside `/EX/clean_url/handp/` folder-
> `Redirect /EX/clean_url/handp/access_denied.php`

This directive is redirecting `/EX/clean_url/handp/<anything>` to `/EX/clean_url/handp/access_denied.php`, which will also catch the redirected request to `access_denied.php` and repeatedly redirect to itself creating a redirect loop, until the browser eventually breaks with a ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS error (after about 20 redirects).

What you needed to do was redirect `/EX/clean_url/handp/` only. You can't do this using `Redirect` since it uses simple prefix-matching. However, you can use the `RedirectMatch` directive that it uses *regex* matching. (But note that this naturally returns a 3xx response to the client, not a 403 Forbidden response as required and exposes your `access_denied.php` script. This is then followed by a 200 OK response when `access_denied.php` is requested, unless you override the HTTP status in the `access_denied.php` script.)

(Note that `Redirect` and `RedirectMatch` are mod_alias directives so do not require the `RewriteEngine On` directive, which is part of mod_rewrite.)

For example:

```
RedirectMatch ^(/EX/clean_url/handp/)$ $1access_denied.php
```

The URL-path is captured in the `$1` backreference and this is used in the target URL (saves repetition).

Alternatively, you could *internally rewrite* the request using mod_rewrite (the URL does *not* change to expose `_access_denied.php`, but you still need to make sure you return the appropriate 4xx HTTP status code from your script). For example:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ access_denied.php [L]
```

Alternatively, you could simply change the `DirectoryIndex` for this (and subsequent) directory:

```
DirectoryIndex /EX/clean_url/handp/access_denied.php
```

If you don't have subdirectories of `/EX/clean_url/handp/`, you could remove the URL-path:

```
DirectoryIndex access_denied.php
```

(Again, you'll need to manually send the 4xx status code from your script.)

Comment: thanks it worked...But why it is not working when i gave relative path like `./access_denied.php` ?

Comment: and can you tell me why `Redirect` is not working in my .htaccess

Comment: I've updated my answer addressing the queries in your comments, plus some alternatives.